# Is RIM Alliance Partner program the only option for blackberry applications when no BES and no APN are provided?

Tags: http, blackberry, networking, connection

I'm here, as many before me, with an HttpConnection problem using the BlackBerry platform (the 4.6.1 in my case).

I need to perform a call to a web service and everything works fine from the emulator (using MDS and WiFi) but when using a real phone (an 8250) only the WiFi works.

My test phone, like many here in Italy, has a BIS data plan and no default APN configuration. As I told, this is a very common configuration for my country phones so I'd like to solve the problem without forcing the user to specify any connection parameter.

I already tried to create an HttpConnection using all the variants of the Connector.Create method:

1. (HttpConnection)Connector.open(uri); // No parameters specified
2. (HttpConnection)Connector.open(uri + **";deviceside=true"**);
3. (HttpConnection)Connector.open(uri + **";deviceside=false"**);
4. (HttpConnection)Connector.open(uri + **";interface=wifi"**);
5. (HttpConnection)Connector.open(uri + **";deviceside=false;ConnectionUID=uid"**);

Number **4**, i.e. WiFi, is the only method working for me.
Number **1** and **3** fail complaing about the missing APN configuration.
Number **2** fails because I'm not connected to a BES infrastructure.
Number **5** fails because the uid retrieved with the code shown into the BB [documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0#6) always return a null value (maybe because WAP2 is not configured?)

I didn't test the WAP1 solution because the average user will probably not know the parameters needed for configuring it.

I've just discovered that also the **"mds-public"** magic string may affect the connection but I still have to investigate on its meaning and the effects on my carrier.

So, finally, the real question: Do you think that the only solution for me is to request the access to the BIS-B service and so to become an Alliance Partner program member? You know, I'd like to be sure before asking to my boss to pay for it if it is not necessary.

Thanks so much in advance,
Alessandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Ok.. I was in hurry and I needed an answer so I cross posted the question on the blackberry forum too (shame on me!).
But I received a really interesting answer over there that I'd like to share with you: [peter_strange answer](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/HttpConnection-over-a-BIS-data-plan-with-no-APN-default-data/m-p/628424/highlight/false#M130594)

> There is a back door to getting BIS-B access.
>
> Fill in a request for for the Push service (free).  This uses BIS-B.  You don't have to use the PUSH service, but you will get access to BIS-B.
>
> As I understand it (from conversations with RIM at DevCon) RIM have not yet gotten round to making BIS-B available to all, because they have not had time to do the legal agreements thing that they need you to do.  but this is already included in the push service.
>
> So no need for Alliance membership, just use the Push service.

Many kudos to peter_strange!

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend that you use this

http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/

We use this in our project, with some modification.

It test every transport available and take the first one that works.

You could also implement your own if you want.

It is currently working in production in Canada and USA on all Carriers. I hope it is going to work in EU too.

Comment: One note to add is that the helper class does do BIS so if you plan on submitting your app to App World and it uses BIS, you might run into legal trouble at some point if you don't have an Alliance Membership with RIM (or maybe it doesn't get approved?).  Don't take my word for it though - I'm not a lawyer!  Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Marc, We submited an to the App World with this code, no problem at all. Since the BIS-B need to be active for this app to be used, and the code detects if it can be used. You can also set it to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know of the most common carriers you will need to support, you can "bake" the APN information into your app so that all it needs to do is check the network using something like [RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkName()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getCurrentNetworkName%28%29) and then map that to an APN to append onto the connection string and use Direct TCP.

You only need APN for GSM carriers, so CDMA should work fine without an APN.

Comment: Thanks, at the end I think that I'll go with this pattern.